# Why is my event variable undefined in this ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get content `Ajax josn`. It works but I get error when handling data.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.blogger.com/feeds/5333031351806450888/pages/default/918209522815033390?alt=json-in-script",
    method: "GET",
    success: function (e) {
        var t;
        for (t = 0; t < e.feed.entry.length; t += 1) {
            var n = $(e.feed.entry[t].content.$t);
            if (0 === t && !$("body").hasClass("error_page")) {
                for (var o = n.find("li"), d = [], a = 0; a < o.length; a += 1) d.push($(o[a]).text());
                var r,
                i = zaxid,
                f = zaxid,
                s = d.length - 1;
                for (r = 0; r < d.length; r += 1) {
                    if ( (-1 != i.indexOf(d[r]))) {
                        var l = $(e.feed.entry[t].content.$t).find("script"),
                        p = $(e.feed.entry[t].content.$t).find("style");
                        $("head").append(p), $("head").append(l);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },          
});
```

but it didn't work got this error

[image]
[image]

any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `e.feed` (or `e.feed.entry`) is undefined - doesn't exist.

Comment: Log `e.feed` to the console before the for loop and see if it actually contains an entry property

Comment: I dont see feed.entry in the retrun from that url.  You are also missing a quotation at the end of the url value, maybe just a typo in the post..  `url: ".. ?alt=json-in-script`

Answer (score 0):

The page at `https://www.blogger.com/feeds/5333031351806450888/pages/default/918209522815033390?alt=json-in-script` that you're fetching returns this content:

```
gdata.io.handleScriptLoaded({"version":"1.0","encoding":"UTF-8","entry":{"xmlns":"http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom","xmlns$gd":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005","id":{"$t":"tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-5333031351806450888.page-918209522815033390"},"published":{"$t":"2020-11-29T08:57:00.002-08:00"},"updated":{"$t":"2020-12-01T11:26:33.705-08:00"},"title":{"type":"text","$t":""},"content":{"type":"html","$t":"\u003cdiv class\u003d\"remain\"\u003e\u003cdiv class\u003d\"redirect\"\u003e\u003cdiv class\u003d\"ops\"\u003e\u003cstyle\u003e.header-panel{text-align:center;font-size:19px;font-family:cairo;background:#fff;color:#666;padding:0;margin:0 auto;width:100%} \u003c/style\u003e\u003cdiv class\u003d\"header-panel\"\u003e\u003cdiv class\u003d\"activetheme\"\u003e\u003ch2\u003eعفوا ! هذا القالب غير مرخص لهذه المدونة\u003c/h2\u003e\u003ch4\u003e\t هذا القالب اذا حصلت عليه بشكل غير قانوني او وجدته في احد المواقع الاخرى فيجب ان يتم تفعيله من طرف مالكه الأصلي\u003ca href\u003d\"https://Twitter.com\"\u003eمن هنا\u003c/a\u003e\t\u003c/h4\u003e\t\u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e \u003c/div\u003e\u003c/div\u003e\u003cul class\u003d\"domains\"\u003e\u003cli\u003e4949659660968074099\u003c/li\u003e\u003c/ul\u003e\u003c/div\u003e"},"link":[{"rel":"edit","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://www.blogger.com/feeds/5333031351806450888/pages/default/918209522815033390"},{"rel":"self","type":"application/atom+xml","href":"https://www.blogger.com/feeds/5333031351806450888/pages/default/918209522815033390"},{"rel":"alternate","type":"text/html","href":"http://ryui87.blogspot.com/p/blog-page.html","title":""}],"author":[{"name":{"$t":"0"},"email":{"$t":"noreply@blogger.com"},"gd$image":{"rel":"http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#thumbnail","width":"35","height":"35","src":"//www.blogger.com/img/blogger_logo_round_35.png"}}]}});
```

so `e`, in your callback, will be a string, so `e.feed` will be undefined, so `e.feed.entry` can't be accessed and that will throw the error you're observing

You're fetching the wrong URL, it's `?alt=json` and not `?alt=json-in-script`. The first one returns JSON, so `e` will be an object, but the latter returns a JS script, so `e` will be a string

Note that that would still crash because `e` will evaluate to `{ entry: <something> }` and not `{ feed: { entry: <something> } }` so your `e.feed.entry` will throw again, you might want to replace these by `e.entry`

Then it might still crash because due to the fact that you didn't provided us with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), we don't know how your DOM looks like, so we can't predict what `$(e.entry[t].content.$t)` will evaluate to